# UICollectionView insert/delete animations

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview

I have to do some updates on my custom UICollectionView after inserting and/or deleting some cells. But I would like to do the updates after the animations (triggered by inserting and/or deleting) are done.

How can I tell when UICollectionView insert/delete animations?

Thanks!

PS: In Swift.

Comment: Mention Obj C/Swift in question.

Comment: It may help you. https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/306-customizing-collection-view-cell-insertion-animations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don’t know if I understand the question correctly but if you don’t want animations you can do this.

```
  self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [oldIndex])

  }, completion: { [unowned self] (_) in
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
  })
```

Comment: You answered my question. Basically, the completion handler in collectionView?.performBatchUpdates() gets called when the animations triggered by inserting or delete are done; which is exactly what I needed to know.